# Route to channel configuration

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to send message through

> 'startChannel->router1->outChannel'

If I comment out 'config-2.xml' content, it work as I expect.

When I enable 'config-2.xml' content, I expect it should send message through

> 'startChannel->router1->routerChannel->router2->outChannel'

but I get following exception.

> EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'routerChannel' cannot be found on
>   object of type
>   'org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage' - maybe not
>   public?

How do I route message to 'routerChannel'?

config-1.xml

```
<int:channel id="startChannel"/>

<int:router id="router1" 
            input-channel="startChannel"
            default-output-channel="outChannel"
            resolution-required="false"
            expression="routerChannel"/>

<int:channel id="outChannel"/>
```

config-2.xml

```
<int:channel id="routerChannel"/>
<int:router id="router2"
            input-channel="routerChannel"
            resolution-required="true"
            expression="payload.paymentType">
    <int:mapping value="CASH" channel="cashPaymentChannel"/>
    <int:mapping value="CREDIT" channel="authorizePaymentChannel"/>
    <int:mapping value="DEBIT" channel="authorizePaymentChannel"/>
</int:router>
```

Comment: Please, add more info. Like: "I expect it should work like, but I get this exception." And so on. And it isn't clear what you mean with "does not exist" . An optional configuration? How it can work if you really how to `<import>` that xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SpEL must be like this:

```
expression="@routerChannel"/>
```

Since it is runtime expression we have to honor its bean reference protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The expression in the router will be evaluated and the result should be string (single channel) or collection of string (multiple channel). In your use case router expression doesn't make sense in config1.xml. If it is direct channel value, there is no use of router here.

Comment: See my answer. Even if it looks weird, I'm sure there may be some use-cases to do that way. And I hope that expression logic is much complex than we have in this topic for simplicity.